# Angular AWS with Wix domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, velo

I have project that I have set up on AWS my backend and RDS and frontend s3 bucket are all setup are working fine.

I need to apply SSL and my domain name to get to the bucket but am having troubles with this. My domain name is registered on Wix, and I am using ACM to get the SSL certificate.

I created a new Cloudfront service and the cloudfront domain name works fine but how do I use my Wix name with SSL

Comment: It doesn't look like a programming issue at all, you should ask to another place (Server Fault ?)

Answer (score 0):

Wix does not support [third-party-ssl](https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-third-party-ssl-certificates), so you won't be able to use ACM with your wix domain.

However, since you registered your domain with Wix, you can easily enable https for your domain. https://support.wix.com/en/article/enabling-https-for-your-wix-site